# FInd items in JSON object using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have this JSON object

```
{
   "manufacturers":[
      {
         "name":"Chevy",
         "cars":[
            {
               "name":"Corvette",
               "colors":[
                  "black",
                  "midnight blue",
                  "silver",
                  "inferno red",
                  "atomic orange"
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Camaro",
               "colors":[
                  "black",
                  "blue",
                  "yellow",
                  "red"
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Ford",
         "cars":[
            {
               "name":"GT",
               "colors":[
                  "light blue",
                  "black"
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Mustang",
               "colors":[
                  "black",
                  "blue",
                  "dark green",
                  "silver"
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Focus RS",
               "colors":[
                  "light blue",
                  "dark blue",
                  "black",
                  "silver"
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Tesla",
         "cars":[
            {
               "name":"S",
               "colors":[
                  "white",
                  "black",
                  "red",
                  "silver",
                  "blue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"3",
               "colors":[
                  "white",
                  "black",
                  "red",
                  "silver",
                  "blue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"X",
               "colors":[
                  "white",
                  "black",
                  "red",
                  "silver",
                  "blue"
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Y",
               "colors":[
                  "white",
                  "black",
                  "red",
                  "silver",
                  "blue"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have to find all card where manufacturer is Ford:

```
var fordCars = apiModel.Manufacturers.Find(o => o.Name == "Ford");
```

It gives me the second object.  How do I get the names of cards, namely GT, mustang and focus from this?

// In Progress
Can I do something like this?

```
var fordCars = apiModel.Manufacturers.Find(o => o.Name == "Ford").Cars.FindAll(o => o.);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you need **all** cars where the manufacturer is Ford, then you have to use [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) instead of [`.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=net-6.0).

```
var fordCars = apiModel.Manufacturers.Where(o => o.name == "Ford");
```

Now if you want list of all car names, then use [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-6.0) after `.Where()` clause,

```
var carNames = fordCars
    .SelectMany(x => x.Cars)  //Convert sequence of car object
    .Select(x => x.Name);     //Select only Name from car object
```

---

Why should we use `.Where()` instead of `.Find()`?

**Find():**

- Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the **first occurrence** within the entire List.

**Where():**

- Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate and returns **all the
  filtered data**

---

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EWOe0o)